# OpenXML C# Exception In Collection Count Method

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I am opening and editing a Word DOCX in the C# OpenXML library.

I have this code:

```
IEnumerable<Break> breaks = p.Descendants<Break>().Where(s => s != null && s.Type == BreakValues.Page);
int count = breaks.Count(); // THIS THROWS EXCEPTION!
```

The exception is:

```
Error in implicit conversion. Cannot convert null object.
    at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.EnumValue`1.op_Implicit(EnumValue`1 xmlAttribute)
    at Reporting.Report.<generate>b__1(Break s)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    at Reporting.Report.generate()
```

However, this

```
Console.WriteLine("breaks == null? : " + (breaks == null));
```

Return false:

```
breaks == null? : False
```

Is this a bug in the library?

--- EDIT ---

```
private int manualCount(IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> col)
{         
    int count = 0;
    if (col == null)
    {
        return count;
    }
    foreach (OpenXmlElement elem in col) 
    {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

The above loop (foreach) errors out with the same issue. Seems to be an OpenXML bug then?

--- EDIT SOLUTION ---

Check first that Type is not null!

```
b.Type != null && b.Type == BreakValues.Page
```

Comment: I also put in a check to see if s is null, and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks one of the item in the p.Descendants() is null

Try out this, where you explicitly ignore items that are null in the list (s != null)

```
IEnumerable<Break> breaks = p.Descendants<Break>().Where(s => s != null && s.Type == BreakValues.Page);
```

If that doesnt work, explicitly loop through it and see what is coming

```
var breaks = p.Descendants<Break>();
foreach(var item in breaks)
{
//debug every item and see what is coming out of item.Type
}
```

EDIT:

Looking more closely into it, the problem is not with an item being null in the collection, it has something to do with converting the "Break" xml node to Break object. It is not possible to convert one of the attribute values to the enum type. i.e I doubt one of the Break node has an attribute called "Page" and the value of it is empty or the Page attribute itself is not there! Just go through the xml and probably you can figure that out!

Probably what you can try out is to change the Break class's "Type" property's data type to string instead of BreakValues.Page enum value - just to see if the theory is correct.

Comment: Doesn't help. This is baffling.

Comment: Changed the order of the condition - check s!= null in the beginning!

Comment: Doesn't help. Seems to be a library issue or possibly C#?

Comment: I very much doubt that. Why dont you explictly loop through it and see what is coming out of p.Descendants<Break>()? Use a normal foreach loop and debug and see every "s.Type" in it - maybe that can give you more insights

Comment: Looking more closely into it, the problem is not with an item being null in the collection, it has something to do with converting the object "break" xml to Break object. It is not possible to convert one of the attribute values to the enum type. i.e I doubt one of the Break node has an attribute called "Page" and the value of it is empty or the attribute itself is not there! Just go through the xml and probably you can figure that out!

Comment: You were right. I had to check for null first for Type, even though it shouldn't error out I believe. Thanks anyways.